# Python JSON multiple requests get response save to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, request

**Input:**

I send multiple get requests with two parameters as lists (Year and Month) using API to import data

**My sample code:**

```
import grequests
import json
import requests 
import io
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize 

api_key = <api_key>
url = <url>
headersAuth = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key,
}

years_list = ['2020', '2021']
month_list = ['1','2']

#Create an array of urls
urls = [url + "Month=" + str(i) + "&Year=" + str(j) for i in month_list for j in years_list]

#Preapare requests
rs = (grequests.get(u, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + api_key}) for u in urls)
response = grequests.map(rs)
json_ = [r.json() for r in response]
```

But after json_ step I stuck, because I'm not sure how to parse this further in the right way

After running my script I get a format that looks like this

```
[
{'ID': 3473, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 1234}, 
{'ID': 3488, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 1789}]
... etc.
```

**Output:**

I would like to export it to pandas dataframe and then to xlsx or csv file as a normal column view
I'm probably missing some basics here, but can't process it further

I tried several things after that:

1. Use json.dumps jsonStr  = json.dumps(json_)
2. Then convert it to listOfDictionaries = json.loads(jsonStr)
3. Then data_tuples = list(zip(listOfDictionaries))
4. df = pd.DataFrame(data_tuples)

But I couldn't get a desired output.
I would appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2):

[`pandas.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
{'ID': 3473, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 1234}, 
{'ID': 3488, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 1789}]

pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)

     ID  Month  Year  Sold
0  3473      1  2020  1234
1  3488      1  2020  1789
```

Comment: Thank you, though It doesn't work in my case and it gives me 4 rows and 275 columns

0    ...                                                274
0  {'ID': 3473, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'S...  ...  {'ID': 2811, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'S...
1  {'ID': 3484, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2021, 'S...  ...                                               None
2  {'ID': 3364, 'Month': 2, 'Year': 2020, 'S...  ...                                               None
3  {'ID': 3442, 'Month': 2, 'Year': 2021, 'S...  ...                                               None


[4 rows x 275 columns]

Comment: Either you aren't using `from_records` or your data looks different than represented.  Give me a bigger data sample.

Comment: It's <class 'list'>. 

Here is a bigger sample. 


[[{'ID': 3473, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 1225}, {'ID': 3488, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 178}, {'ID': 2692, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 1059}, {'ID': 3044, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 1538}, {'ID': 3085, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 2073}, {'ID': 3275, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 6}, {'ID': 3537, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 262}, {'ID': 3484, 'Month': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 0},  {'ID': 3695, 'Month': 2, 'Year': 2021, 'Sold': 0}]]

Comment: That is a list of length one whose only element is a list.  Use `pd.DataFrame.from_records(data[0])` instead.

Comment: pd.DataFrame.from_records(data[1])  also gives me data. 
As well as data[2] and data[3]. 
So it's  a length of four. Probably because I took 2020, 2021 as years and 1, 2 as months.
 
Could you please suggest what I can do in this case? Because I will need to add more data like other years and months. So the list will grow.

Comment: I can't help any further without a [mcve].  Otherwise, I'm just guessing at your problem and that wastes both of our time.

Comment: You're right. Here is a better sample, it gives a better picture.

Comment: [[{'ID': 3473, 'M': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 1225}, {'ID': 3488, 'M': 1, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 178}], [{'ID': 3484, 'M': 1, 'Year': 2021, 'Sold': 0}, {'ID': 3310, 'M': 1, 'Year': 2021, 'Sold': 0}], [{'ID': 3364, 'M': 2, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 24}, {'ID': 2717, 'M': 2, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 1}, {'ID': 2719, 'M': 2, 'Year': 2020, 'Sold': 6}], [{'ID': 3442, 'M': 2, 'Year': 2021, 'Sold': 0}, {'ID': 3471, 'M': 2, 'Year': 2021, 'Sold': 0}, {'ID': 2717, 'M': 2, 'Year': 2021, 'Sold': 1}, {'ID': 2719, 'M': 2, 'Year': 2021, 'Sold': 3},  {'ID': 3204, 'M': 2, 'Year': 2021, 'Sold': 62}]]

Comment: So it's a list and inside there are four sets of data. 
I guess It's four sets because 2 years of data and 2 months were requested.